# How to contain particles within object?

Tags: particles

this may be a stupid question, but I only really use blender casually and I need some help for a project. I'm doing a thing where I want to have rose petals flying around in an animation, so I'm using a particle system emitting rose petals. However, when I set the particles to fly around (I have them flying around using Brownian and the gravity set to 0), by the end of the animation, they are all flying outwards when I want them to stay within a certain boundary. I've scoured through every single option the particle tab has to offer, looked through dozens of tutorials, but none of them seem to solve the problem. I know there is a way to contain particles within an object, such as a cube, but I just haven't been able to find how. It is worth noting that I have tried emitting particles via both a plane and a cube, just to see if i could make it work both ways, however both have failed.

Comment: If you want them to stay within a boundary... have you created a boundary or how should the particles know where the boundary is? Maybe a plane with collision on it? The problem is, all the settings in the Particles Tab are for emitting the particles. To stop them you need external obstacles (or just let them die by setting a short lifetime).

Comment: i've tried adding planes with collision stuff on there, but it always causes a lot of glitches with how they work. i tried a cube but it just caused them all to stick to each other and stick to the edges of the cube.

Answer (score 1):

Just duplicate your original object and for the duplicated object:

1. Remove its particle system(particle system also duplicates while duplicating an object)
2. Go to *Physics Properties*, and click on *Collision*
3. Select your original object and bake the particle system
4. Delete the duplicated object

Comment: This just makes my rose petals go completely everywhere and glitch out. When I try it with the cube, it causes the petals to glitch to the sides of the cube, and when I try it with the plane, it kinda works but a copy of the petals all fall down and continue to fall, while there is still no boundaries.

Comment: Can you provide your .blend file? https://blend-exchange.com